# WordPress get tags in "publish_post" hook

Tags: wordpress

I want to get the selected tags in the `publish_post` hook while publishing the post.

With the below code, I can get only those tags that are already saved in the post. this will not work for new tags.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );

function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $post_tags = get_the_tags($ID);
    if ( $post_tags ) {
        print_r($post_tags);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? I think you can get new tags also as they are saving on the go

Comment: Yes I test it, it is not returning new tags. :(

Comment: I think this call is before saving the post.

Comment: try exit after print_r($post_tags); and see what it returns

Comment: Yes, I tried exit as well. If the post is new it will return nothing and if the post is old it returns the existing saved tags but not newly added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200880/discussion-between-prashant-patil-and-vidya-l).